# How to keep third party content under control inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am running into the following situation:

```
<body>
<div style="width:300px;border:1px dotted black;" id="myhopelessdiv">
    This is a sample evil image:
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>
    This is a sample evil inside table:
    <table width="500" border="1">
      <tr><td>Hello</td><td>World</td></tr>
    </table>
    And some sample evil inside div:
    <div>
      With some evil content:
      Some info...<br>
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
      And some other info...<br>
   </div>       
</div>
</body>
```

The issue is that everything inside "myhoplessdiv" is external content that I cannot change, but I want it to follow the rules I need, and that is that the content fits inside some width I set (in this example 300px). Is there any style combination that I can apply on "myhoplessdiv" that will enable children elements to do `word-wrap:break-word`, images to fit inside the div, or at least keep them from showing outside the div?

I have no influence on the content that`s inside the div, I can count with crappy html, just want to have some control over the area on which it is displayed...

Comment: I liked `myhoplessdiv` here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#myhoplessdiv {
    word-wrap:break-word;

    /* maybe you were looking for this */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;

    /* everything else */


    /* don't forget your width/height */
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

You should set a finite width and height for the div.

Even if you have paddings, margins, etc inside that #myhopeless div of yours, it'll stick to your set dimension. [Box Sizing | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

You can also `overflow:hidden;` to hide overflowing contents inside your div.

You might need to change `word-break: break-word;` to `word-break: break-all;`.

**EDIT**

Here's a quicky solution when I looked at your codes. Should have done this from the start.

```
#myhopelessdiv > div, #myhopelessdiv img, #myhopelessdiv table {
    width:100%;
}
```

You should at least expect what kinds of contents you will be getting, maybe their IDs or CLASSES too.

Note: If you don't know what kind of data/content you'll be getting, and there's no uniformity with their container, this might not be a good solution for you.

Also, regarding with `overflow:hidden;` you could do an `overflow:auto;` instead so you'd have this scroll function.

Comment: However, when my content has the opposed style somewhere: `word-wrap: normal` it still doesn`t look right. And the content of the div is still visible outside... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Martin What kind of external content it is btw? A whole webpage? Or an XML, JSON or AJAX (in html) response?

Comment: OK, `overflow:hidden` keeps the mess hidden at least... :) That`s a good start... I cannot set height as it can be half a screen long or 5 screens, but that`s not really an issue, the width is what I need to set and it`s done that way...

Comment: It´s kind of a whole webpage, it´s a html styled document that can come from various sources... I have no influence over how it is generated... Important is to keep it under control...

Comment: I'd recommend overflow:auto; -- check out my updates.

Comment: I changed your last suggestion a bit and replaced width with max-width, so smaller elements don`t get affected. Is there a way to make all children `elements max-width:100%`? Something like `#myhopelessdiv > *`?

Comment: @Martin Oh yeah. That was the thing I forgot when I edit my post. I put > div instead. Lol.

Comment: To make all children elements max width is #myhopelessdiv > * > * {max-width:100%;} -- or you could use the border-box for #myhopelessdiv > * Because by doing so (ref to first solution), you might potentially ruined some div or table cell with max-width with smaller than 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
#myhopelessdiv {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

So if the content is bigger than your div, its simply cutted off.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's not in an iframe, you can just apply styles under `#myhopelessdiv`.

```
#myhopelessdiv {
    width: 700px !important; /* !important is to override the inline style */
}
#myhopelessdiv * {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: After applying it, inside elements are still bigger than the div... If I put some contradicting style inside it breaks again...

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
#myhopelessdiv img, #myhopelessdiv table{
max-width:300px;
}
```

this will work for sure.

Comment: Have you tried running my sample? The div is sized at exactly 300px, but the content is larger and overlaps outside the div... With max-width the same happens...